# Could the scalar projection be negative?

Tags: vectors

could the scalar projection be negative? It means magnitude in a sense, isn't it?

Comment: The scalar projection is $|A|\cos\theta$. Whether or not it's negative depends on $\theta$. (It's signed magnitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar projection of $a$ onto $b$ can be defined in the following ways:

$$ s = \|a\|\cos{\theta} = \frac{a\cdot b}{\|b\|} $$

This shows that the result can be negative. Geometrically this will occur when $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Algebraically it will occur when $a\cdot b < 0$.